# TFS connection user versus username

Tags: git, tfs, tfs-2015

On TFS 2015 GIT (on premises, not online), security seems to be applied based on the user's connection (matching the username and password to establish the connection to TFS).

However, what shows in GIT log is a "fantasy name" that is usually set by default as the same user as the connection's; if for example I change it from my username to a different (even non existing) user name, that is what will display in the history and logs.

Is there any way of finding out the real user connection used to push something to TFS?

Comment: Did you want to display other's connection username on just your own？

Comment: As an admin I want to know who exactly committed/pushed code. If all we see is a name that can be changed by every developer I may never know.